# Existance of Schauder Basis of vector space over field F implies separability

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, separable-spaces, schauder-basis

It's rather trivial to prove that when a normed vector space X over the real numbers, or the complex numbers, has a Schauder Basis then X is separable.
Since you can construct a dense&countable set by using the rational numbers, which you know are countable.

What I'm wondering is, what can we say when **X is a vector space over an arbitrary Field F**. Can we still find a countable set and then proceed to show that it's also dense? Or is it necessary to take X as a vec space over R/C ?

Comment: I would assume this depends on the topology of the vector space. In the real/complex case we are always talking about normed spaces. But that is not possible with arbitrary fields, so there is a non-trivial choice there I think.